# Asus USB N10 wireless scans but doesn't connect Wheezy or Arch

Tags: debian, archlinux, wireless

I am trying to setup my wireless dongle for my Pi, but it will not connect.

It is the [Asus USB N10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VGQQAE) recommended by many users.  It has the drivers built into both Arch and Wheezy, but I cannot get it to connect.  It will scan and display the wireless networks.  I have tried to connect to unsecured networks as well as WPA encrypted networks but it won't connect.

I am using a 5V/2 Amp power source with just a keyboard, the dongle, and the Ethernet connected.  I am in the CLI interface using the HDMI out.  Software for connecting is wpa_supplicant for encryption and the basic wireless-tools supplied in the OSs.

In Arch when I try to connect using the command as root

`ip link set wlan0 up`

I get a

`RTNETLINK answers: operation not permitted`

In Wheezy I use the command as root

`/etc/init.d/network restart`

and I get

```
Listening on LPF/wlan0/ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful if you provide some more details like how did you set up your system, what commands/applications are you using and what error messages you get.

Comment: I'm guessing its a power issue. Have you tried using a powered hub?

Comment: Hi @Ge3ng. Welcome to Stack Exchange. We need a few more details to help. How are you trying to connect for example?

Comment: Here's someone using the same stick http://alexcollins.org/blog/2012/raspberry-pi-and-the-asus-usb-n10-wifi-dongle

Answer (score 1):

Try using wpa_cli to connect and see if it connects.
If it does connect, then you can add the details into /etc/network/interfaces to get it to automatically connect.

Instructions for wpa_cli here - http://sirlagz.net/?p=666

Comment: I'm not sure there are enough details in the question to judge whether this is a solution or not.

Comment: You're probably right about that. Worth a shot if he is already using a Powered Hub though. I'm going on the assumption he's tried basic troubleshooting - which I probably shouldn't have done in the first place :D

Comment: This didn't work I got the same results.

Comment: What errors came up when you tried it with wpa_cli ?